# When will podcasts be automatically deleted in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, podcasts, defaults, macos

I've heard that downloaded podcasts that are visited would be automatically deleted after some time. But I'm not sure about when or which condition does this occur.

When will the downloaded podcast episodes be automatically deleted if not saved? How to control this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this for each podcast subscription. Click on the Gear icon at the top of a podcast list to bring up the Podcast Settings dialog.

The 'Limit Episodes' choice gives you a number of ways to set how many podcasts are retained, including no limit.

Comment: Great! So if you leave this to default, none of your podcasts will be deleted automatically, right?

Comment: I believe so. I have one set of podcasts from 3 years ago that haven't been deleted.

Comment: Thanks, Greg. So I guess I wouldn't have to save every new podcast I download as long as I stick to the default. That's another load off my mind.

Comment: Great if you want to retain old podcasts, but what if you want to have iTunes automatically delete old podcasts, even those that were never played?